# Forecasts fail for new period

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting, prophet

I am working with prophet library in python where I do some forecasts. While I split to train and test to check, it shows very good performance, but when I forecast for the actual future period it loses everything. See photo below:

[image]

Any ideas as to why this would occur?

Also, here is the part in my function that I do the forecasting:

```
resampled_data = data.resample(granularity, on='created_at').agg({y_col: 'sum', regressor: 'nunique'}).reset_index()

    # Normalize data
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    resampled_data['normalized_y'] = scaler.fit_transform(resampled_data[[y_col]])

    # Define train and test data
    train = resampled_data.iloc[-(3*30 + 2*period):-period]
    test = resampled_data.iloc[-period:]

    model = Prophet(interval_width=prophet_intervals)
    model.add_country_holidays(country_name='CY')
    model.add_regressor(regressor)
    model.fit(train.rename(columns={'created_at': 'ds', 'normalized_y': 'y'}))

    future = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=2*period, freq=granularity)
    future = future.merge(resampled_data[['created_at', regressor]], left_on='ds', right_on='created_at', how='left')

    # Fill NaN values in the regressor column
    future[regressor].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

    forecast_out = model.predict(future)
```

I think I understand why it does it. I think it's because I use a regressor for which I don't have the data for the forecasted period. No it produces NaN which are then filled with the last observed value. So my regressor has a constant value for the period I want to forecast.
How do I handle this?

The actual data looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do the real data do? I don’t see them on your plot.

Comment: Hello, and thank you! They are exactly as the previous periods.

Comment: Could you please plot the actual data? You have a nice line in blue showing the rest of the data. Perhaps continue that with the forecasts plotted on a different color.

Comment: @Dave I edited my question

Answer (score 3):

It looks like hourly data with a clear daily cycle and weekend effect. Interestingly the last day in your data (Thursday I guess) has a different pattern -> holiday effect? ; did you account for that in your features?

Have you tried the basics first like seasonal decomposition/forecasting? Rob Hyndman has several algorithms in that area for improved forecasting of multi-seasonal time series. See e.g. https://pkg.robjhyndman.com/forecast/reference/msts.html

Also I suggest using sthg else than prophet, especially for the basics like seasonal time series forecasting. Why?  Have a look at Peter Cottons excellent take on prophet at [" Microprediction -
Is Facebook's "Prophet" the Time-Series Messiah, or Just a Very Naughty Boy?"](https://www.microprediction.com/blog/prophet).

He actually goes into very much detail on failures specifically for cyclic time series.  And offers a better API for prophet and other forecasting tools at microprediction.com / https://github.com/microprediction

Comment: Rob Hyndman is my idol :D I did try the decomposition and some naive methods which would capture it but not as good as prophet with holidays into account, etc. I think the problem was as I described it in my question. My regressor did not have values for the period to be forecasted and was producing NaNs. To fix this I carried the last value forward to fill them and that is how I lost the seasonalisty of it, while the trend was downwards. I did two models instead and I forecast the regressor variable and use those forecasts as the regressor for the main model. Maybe I should answer it?

Comment: Yes, right.  You need to do a one step at a time forecast, concatenate it with data from last k-1 steps, and feed it back in as 'x' .   See also comment in Microprediction blog - their wrapper API does it automatically